# ModuleNotFoundError with one Prefect flow, but not the other

Tags: python, docker, prefect

Cross-posting this question: https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/discussions/6868

I have a minimal project using Prefect v1.3.1, which you can find here: https://github.com/b-long/aid . I'm having a little difficulty getting the deployment right, after migrating from native code to dockerized code. I am using the latest version of Prefect v1 and need to solve this before I'm able to migrate to Prefect 2.x

I'm using Poetry, but I'm pretty sure there's a pattern here that would apply to Hatch, Pipenv, Flit or other tooling. The problem is observed in registration which logs this toward the end:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aid'

The command '/bin/sh -c python /opt/prefect/healthcheck.py '["/opt/prefect/flows/basic-pandas-flow.prefect"]' '(3, 10)'' returned a non-zero code: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: Your docker image failed to build!  Your flow might have failed one of its deployment health checks - please ensure that all necessary files and dependencies have been included.
```

If you're a Prefect Guru, I'm guessing you'll be able to solve this issue by reading the log file (see discussion linked above) and looking at my Dockerfile: https://github.com/b-long/aid/blob/main/Dockerfile.prefect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your package `aid` is relative to `/` root file system

```
COPY README.md aid/ /aid/
```

I believe it will work if you make it relative to `/aid` dir (your working dir is `/aid` and so init file need to be in `/aid/aid/__init__.py`)

```
COPY README.md /aid/
COPY aid/ /aid/aid
```

Comment: This, ultimately, was the clue that solved it! Thanks @Anton I'll provide additional details later today or tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

I answered directly on the GitHub issue. Let's keep the discussion there to make it easier to follow everything in one place.

Btw, great writeup on the GitHub issue, very helpful!

Comment: While I truly appreciate the help, I don't want to pay the bounty for this answer since it seems unresolved. If we can have some more conversation via GitHub, I'll happily mark this answer as the solution :)